# openssl on Windows does not recoginize my -extfile

Tags: windows, openssl, ssl-certificate

When using OpenSSL 1.0.2l, I have the following command line:

```
openssl ca -out certs\cert.pem -days 1825 -config openssl.cnf -infiles requests\req.pem -extfile "v3.ext"
```

I have the v3.ext file in the current directory:

```
>dir v3.ext
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 1E1A-0C21

 Directory of C:\Users\[me]\.openssl

06/12/2017  10:58 AM               205 v3.ext
               1 File(s)            205 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  116,381,810,688 bytes free
```

When I run it, I get this error message:

> -extfile: No such file or directory
>   8932:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:406:fopen('-extfile','rb')
>   8932:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:408:

This is a Windows 10 box. Is anything wrong with my Extfile option?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Comment: The reference you provided for this site includes the following as appropriate: "software tools commonly used by programmers;".  This would certainly include openssl.  You will also note various tags on this site for SSL, openssl, etc. The openssl tag here already includes 8829 questions as of today. I believe this is appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "-extfile" option should be earlier in the list of options. From the ca man page (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-ca.html):

```
-infiles
if present this should be the last option, all subsequent arguments are 
assumed to the the names of files containing certificate requests.
```

So your "-extfile" argument is being taken as a request file.

Comment: It seems like the command should warn when it encounters a leading dash (`-`) as part of the name of a file. Its unusual to see files named that way, especially on Windows. Or maybe better, start arguments for a new option.

Comment: This also happens on Linux and for later versions (here 1.1.1g).

Comment: the link for this answer has broken.

Comment: Link fixed (now pointing at the 3.0 version of the man page since 1.0.2 is now end of life)